# Print the number of subarrays of an array having negative sums

Tags: algorithms, searching

**Problem statement**: Given an array of N integers, find its number of negative subarrays (i.e sub arrays having negative summation). E.g: for an array $[1,-2, 4, -5, 1]$ there are 9 subarrays whose sum is negative. Subarray means sequential array within an array.

**My code**: It's complexity is $\theta(n^{2})$ as we can see. I have applied brute force technique. How can I improve my code/pseudocode?

```
    int sum=0,count=0;
    for(int i=1,k,j;i<=N;i++){
        for(k=1;k<=N-i+1;k++){
            for(j=0;j<i;j++){
                sum += arr[j+k-1];
            }
            if(sum<0)
                count++;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like $\Theta(n^3)$ to me.

Comment: sum should be set to zero just before the "for (j = ..." loop and nowhere else. Try to prove the correctness of your code which requires that sum must be zero just at that point - much easier if that is the point where you set it.

Comment: @gnasher729 This code has been successfully passed all the test cases on a competitive platform. We have to set sum = 0 always as to ensure previous summation doesn't reflect in newer summation. And this code checking all $\frac{n*(n+1)}{2}$ sub arrays individually so $\theta(n^{2})$ .

Comment: " This code has been successfully passed all the test cases on a competitive platform." -- That doesn't tell us anything about $\Theta$-s.

Comment: And who told  you the testcase statement was a reason of complexity question? @Raphael It was to answer code is correct.

Comment: It can't show that either, of course! But it's a strong hint, if the test set isn't completely bogus.

Comment: "And this code checking all n∗(n+1)/2 sub arrays individually so θ(n2)" -- since the arrays are of average linear length, it's cubic time. You get the same if you [properly investigate](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) the nested loops.

Comment: Yes @Raphael You are right. it is $\theta(n^{3})$ as it is forming $N+(N-1)*2+(N-2)*3+...+N$ series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An $O(n \log n)$ solution:

Find prefix sums $S[i] = \sum_{k=0}^{i} a[k]$

Set $S[-1] = 0$

Now count the number of inversion pairs in $S[-1], S[0], \dots, S[n-1]$

Comment: Thanks. how this work? Can you little elaborate. I checked with some examples but couldn't understand intuitively why it is working .

Comment: @Fire: $S[j+k], S[j]$ is an inversion pair implies $S[j+k] - S[j] < 0$ and so $a[j+1] + \dots + a[j+k] \lt 0$. The $S[-1]$ helps with sub-arrays starting at $a[0]$.